# Apache RewriteRule replace url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to modify the .htaccess file to obtain an URL translation as seen here:

www.example.com/site/blahblahblah/files/a.jpg     ->     www.example.com/site/files/a.jpg

something like:

```
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/files/(.*)$ files/$1 [L]
```

but it is not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !site/files/?.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (files)/?(.*)
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/site/%1/%2 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Will rewrite this:

`http://www.example.com/site/blahblahblah/files/a.jpg`

To this:

`http://www.example.com/site/files/a.jpg`